# Looking for SQL Optimization Interview Questions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm on a project where I was asked to take a quick peek at some reporting SQL (in a SQL Server 2K5 environment) and was surprised at what I found: 4 to 5 levels of subquerys, distinct clauses, unions, and NoLock hints (which were needed because the SQL was running so long it was blocking standard processing) - all in the same set!.

Because I (foolishly :) mentioned that I thought the SQL was inefficient I've been labeled the "expert" and have been tasked with creating a test for a couple of interviewees to do that will assess their SQL optimizing abilities. I'm hoping someone can point me to some URLS, or maybe provide a list that I can use to help weed out the good from the bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned the SQL Server 2005 environment:

[More SQL Server interview questions than you possibly could have imagined:](http://www.mssqltips.com/category.asp?catid=46)

[The classic set.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/20/sql-server-2008-interview-questions-and-answers-complete-list-download/) Most interviewees will probably have studied these...maybe a good way to gauge who has prepared.

[Another classic](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/iq.htm)

[Questions](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-interview-questions/) from one of the [original](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/05/stackoverflow-vc-sql-server-and-whuffie/) Stack Overflow DBAs

Another link for best [SQL questions and answers](http://www.techieclues.com/database-management/ms-sql/questions-and-answers/page-1/)

Comment: Uh ... WOW - you've provided me with a LOT of reading, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, maybe too much to sift through. The MSSQL Tips questions are broken down and there is a Performance Tuning set. Brent's post is definitely worth reading. I think the idea of showing them what they'll need to refactor is excellent. You can get a sense of their skill and they'll get an idea of what they'll be working on.

Comment: +1: Only thing I'd add is to consider googling "TSQL Challenges" for code testing.  I wouldn't expect perfect answers, but a candidate who knows these challenges is someone who is definitely interested in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank's for you comments; one thing I failed to mention was that ... uhm ... the set of questions is due on Monday :$ (hey, nothing like a little dead-line pressure to get the blood flowing!). @8kb thanks for your detailed list, and again for pairing it back to something I can cram into a weekend :P (I've been recently following Brent's blog [one of his posts were the primary motivator for creating a Stack Overflow acct]). @OMG Ponies - good call on the TSQL Challenges, if for nothing else then only to confirm that my original assumption of tonnes of distincts with unions just ain't cool. :)

Comment: +1 for the great links (even if I haven't touched SQL Server in years) and especially for that last link to Brent Ozar's blog (even if it's mostly unrelated to the question).

Answer (score 1):

I would give them a Query plan (via EXPLAIN, or whatever your flavor of SQL uses as a keyword) and see if they can decipher what it means, what the weak points are, and how to improve the query.

Look at [MySQL's Explain Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) for help using MySQL's explain and what it means.

Comment: Thanks @Dan D. I hadn't even thought of utilizing an "Execution Plan"; my focus was more along drafting some poorly written SQL (much like the reporting SQL that started this) and saying "What wrong with this?". I like your idea and will do some digging (ultimately I guess I'll still need that bad SQL to generate an Execution Plan).